# Getting Variable from other function

Tags: rust

I don't know how to get (_s) variable from other function. Maybe there is a way to reformat this script, so it could work or any other way.

```rust
fn shapes(data: usize) {
    let romb = "hello";
    let s_array = [romb];
    let mut items_array = -1;

    print!("{}", s_array[data]);
    if items_array == _s { //<-------this _s variable is not in this function, so it doesn't work
    } else {
        println!("error");
    }
    for x in &s_array {
        items_array = items_array + 1;
    }

    print!("{}", items_array);
}

fn main() {
    let mut _s = String::new();
    let _b1 = std::io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut _s)
        .expect("failed to read line");
    let mut _s = _s.trim_end();

    let _s_int = _s.parse::<usize>().unwrap();

    shapes(_s_int);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add, but the first block of code is in another function

Comment: An underscore (_) at the start of a variable indicates that the variable will not be used, which is clearly not the case here. You should rename it to something meaningful, or at least remove the leading underscore.

Comment: I will delete underscore, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another parameter to your `shapes` function to pass `_s`. So extend the prototype of your function like:

```
fn shapes(data: usize, _s: String) {
    //Use _s here
}
```

to call it like:

```
shapes(_s_int, _s);
```